# May I link to SRD in a document under OGL?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, house-rules, ogl, intellectual-property

I am writing a house rules document for a Pathfinder game. Not publishing it would be a pity, and not using OGL to publish it likewise, since publishing the house rules under OGL allows others to use the same content.

**Can I add links to various SRDs in the document?**

For example, if I link to the website of Paizo, the link might be http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/gettingStarted.html. The link contains the word *paizo*, which is designated as product identity in Paizo's SRD. I suspect that this is also the case with SRDs maintained by third parties.

**Quoting or not quoting text from other OGL content**

Currently I do not quote any text from any other OGL publication (aside from the license text). Later, I may quote such material, which would make it necessary for me to attribute the text to its proper source. Suppose the source is a Pathfinder product (and the quoted text is open content). Does this change the answer to the first question?

**Content of the document**

The document has content such as: "Player may choose zero or one traits for the character, or two traits and one drawback."

It also contains more substantial content, such as a rewritten version of the content of this blog post: https://ropeblogi.wordpress.com/2016/05/25/religious-tenets-for-clerics/

Comment: Bear in mind that links are not guaranteed to be static - they can rework the SRD at any time and change the page names.

Answer (score 2):

#### Can I add links to various SRDs in the document?

Yes, you almost certainly can. The [D20 PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/) does it all the time. If you add a copyright notice according to [section 6 of the OGL](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/openGameLicense.html), there shouldn't be anything objectionable.

#### Quoting or not quoting text from other OGL content

Again, according to section 6, you need to add a copyright notice. Then you should be clear.

Comment: D20pfsrd uses the Pathfinder compatibility license http://www.d20pfsrd.com/extras/community-use which gives them explicit permission to use product identity, such as the phrase Pathfinder roleplaying game.

Answer (score -1):

Links are, generally, not subject to copyright and can be used freely. However, as links are subject to linkrot(Paizo might well decide to take down the original PRD or change the addresses, especially now that PF2e is out. Paizo.com might even leave their hands either inadvertently, or if they go bust), it's generally not adviced to use links unnecessarily.